# Question about using Maple's arrow (->) notation

Tags: complex-numbers, maple

Hi can someone show me how to do this:

> Your function should take a Maple list of complex numbers as its input and return the largest modulus from that list.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have nothing so far, my notes are at home so I won't be able to reach them in until a few days. Just need an example. @Gunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the `map` command to apply the `abs` command to some such list. Then apply the `max` command to that. Now repeat, by composing that second operation around the first. Finally, create an operator which takes `L` to that composed operation applied to `L`.

Look to the help-pages `?max`, `?map`, `?abs`, and `?operators,functional`, if necessary.

Comment: `f := L -> someoperation(L)` where `someoperation` is your composed action involving `max`, `map`, and `abs`. Then you can apply `f` to lists of complex numbers, eg. `f([1+I, 4-3*I, 2-I])`.